# How do I promade

Tags: butter, mixing

I was following a recipe and it stated:

> In a mixing bowl add soft butter
>
> Make it promade.

What does that mean?

Comment: Can you provide more of the recipe? A link if it's online, a bigger quote or even a scan/photo if not?

Comment: Typo is my guess.

Answer (score 4):

*En pomade* is a French term used in cooking. It means "the consistency of hair pomade"

For your recipe, it means to whip/cream the butter until smooth.

Comment: Looks like it's *pommade* in French? http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/pomade

Comment: It looks like sloppy usage. Pommade in French - Pomade used in English translation and reference to the French term.